# Graphing This Function as a Cumulative Distribution

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, statistics

I'm trying to create a cumulative distribution graph of the following function in Python, from -infinity to infinity:

[image]

Initially I tried this code I found online, which seems to work for functions such as x**2:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def graph(formula, x_range):
    x = np.array(x_range)
    y = eval(formula)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()

#graph('(4/5)*(((x**4)/4)+x)', range(-100, 100))

graph('x**2', range(-100, 100))
```

Result:
[image]

The problem is I'm not sure how to translate this code to take into account the other conditions of the functions into this graph (i.e, 0 if x <= 0, 0 if x>=1).  If this code can't be modified to take these two conditions into account, any other suggestions on code that could do this?

Comment: Cdf, by definition, is equal to 1 for x greater than the greatest value of the support of the distribution (i.e. the set on which the density is nonzero). In this case the support is the interval (0, 1), so your formula should say F(x) = 1 for x >= 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your condition as a mask and then make use of NumPy array indexing to assign the values of y to 0 for regions you want to.

Couple of changes:

- I have used `linspace` to have a fine mesh so as to include more data points between `x=0` and `x=1`. The `range` you were using generates integer so you will have basically a straight line between 0 and 1 otherwise.
- `y[(x<=0) | (x>=1)] = 0` is the key thing here. The `|` operator merges the two conditions `(x<=0) | (x>=1)` and returns indices from x-array where this condition holds `True`. Those indices are then used as an input to your y-array and then those values are assigned to 0.

I have restricted the x-limits to -1.5 to 1.5 so as to highlight the interesting region.

**Complete answer for x^2 case**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def graph(formula, x_range):
    x = np.array(x_range)
    y = eval(formula)

    y[(x<=0) | (x>=1)] = 0
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.xlim(-1.5,1.5)
    plt.show()

graph('x**2', np.linspace(-100, 100, 10000))
```

**Plot for your actual equation**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def graph(formula, x_range):
    x = np.array(x_range)
    y = eval(formula)

    y[(x<=0) | (x>=1)] = 0
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.xlim(-1.5,1.5)
    plt.show()

graph('(4/5)*(((x**4)/4)+x)', np.linspace(-100, 100, 10000))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: These plots should show the curve continuing at 1 for x >= 1. I know you've just implemented OP's formula, I've made a comment about fixing that.

Comment: @Robert Dodier: That’s the maths/technical part which I am not aware of . But thanks for your comment. Let’s see what OP actually wants